# Как определить номер недели если неделя начинается с определенного дня?

Tags: java, excel, calendar

При автоматизации отчета в excel, застрял с одной формулой. Формула позволяет проставить номер недели исходя из даты.

Формула:

```
=ЕСЛИ(AH2="Ночь";НОМНЕДЕЛИ(K2;12)-1&" нед.";НОМНЕДЕЛИ(K2;2)-1&" нед.")
```

В столбце К записаны даты в таком формате.

> 07.10.2017 14:02:53

В столбце AH проставляется ночь/день.

Есть идеи как это реализовать?

Вот так формула не учитывает числа 12 и 2, называемые "тип возврата".
из справочника 12 - неделя начинается со вторника.
2 - неделя начинается с понедельника.

```
int week = 0;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
try {
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(dateTo));
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
if(rowX[33].equals("Ночь")){
    week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)-1;
} else {
    week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)-1;
}
rowX[32] = String.valueOf(week);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать первый день недели можно методом [`Calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setFirstDayOfWeek(int)):

```
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.TUESDAY);
//номер недели, начиная со вторника -1
week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)-1;
```

если далее нужно будет на этом же объекте календаря считать с понедельника то потребуется вызвать `cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY)`.

Первый день недели по-умолчанию зависит от локали, т.ч. для пущей стабильности не помешает и понедельник устанавливать явно.